# How to use DataTables in case of dynamic rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm new to the concept of DataTables and I'm referring to [this](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) example.
The only difference in my case is that my HTML table is dynamic. HTML code for my table is as follows:

```
<table id="table_id">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

In my script tag I dynamically add rows to this table using insertRow() method and fetching data from a local json file as follows:

```
    var DemoTable = document.getElementById("table_id");
    var DemoRow, DemoCell1, DemoCell2, DemoCell3;   

    $("#table_id").find("tr:gt(0)").remove(); //to keep the first row headings as set in the html code

for(var i=0; i<DemoData.length; i++) //DemoData contains the fetched json data
        {

            var DemoRow = DemoTable.insertRow();
            DemoCell1 = DemoRow.insertCell(0);
            DemoCell2 = DemoRow.insertCell(1);
            DemoCell3 = DemoRow.insertCell(2);
            DemoCell1.innerHTML = DemoData[i]["Data1"];
            DemoCell2.innerHTML = DemoData[i]["Data2"];
            DemoCell3.innerHTML = DemoData[i]["Data3"];

        }
```

Also, I've included `jquery.dataTables.min.js` and `dataTables.bootstrap.min.js` in the same order.
After this, I've added:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('#table_sub_id').DataTable();
    } );
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageButton' of undefined
```

Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: what do you mean by "HTML table is dynamic" ?

Comment: sheesh. some people are just too lazy to read the code example^^

Comment: all of the code should be in the `$(document).ready(function(){...})` not just the datatables.

Comment: @Pamblam I'll try it thanks :)

Comment: and also call `$('#table_sub_id').DataTable();` after you have added rows to the table.

Comment: unless I'm misunderstanding something, DataTable should be able to read your json directly and build the table for you.

Comment: also, your table needs to have a `<tbody></tbody>` to append your rows to. also, you are removing the header row, which is mandatory for datatables. remove this: `$("#table_id").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();`

Comment: thank you @WhoAmI as well! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you can use this:

```
$('#table_id').DataTable( {
    "ajax": "data/objects.txt",
    "columns": [
        { "data": "cell1" },
        { "data": "cell2" },
        { "data": "cell3" }
    ]
});
```